# URL encode can bypass xss filetering?

Tags: php, xss

The second piece of code here http://anautonomouszone.com/blog/xss-cheat-sheet, claims to bypass html special chars filtering (meaning, <>) by url encoding:

```
Bypass filter when it strips <script> tags:
%253cscript%253ealert(document.cookie)%253c/script%253e
```

Obviously this is URL encoding, which make the server unaware of the original content, but I can't possibly see when does it translate back into `<script>`.

The server gets it like this, and send it back. HTTP content is not encoded, so the user will get it as it is.

What am I missing? Is this true for php function `htmlspecialchars`?

**EDIT :**

After I got quite misunderstood at the chat, I'll try to make myself clear.

This is taken from an XSS cheat sheet. And other XSSes tutorials. Meaning, it's a method for trying to *bypass* some methods that are *against* XSS.

What I'm trying to understand is simple:

- What methods can it bypass (namely, under what scenario will this be helpful for an attacker)?
- And *how* does it happen? When does it decoded to become back `<script>` in the http-respone?
- What can I do to be safe from that in my web site?

Notice, this is in MANY sites, so it probably doesn't refer to an one-in-million-developer-mistake, but something quite likely in a way.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think some browsers (IE?!) interpret this still as <script>. Therefore, the author tells us not just to strip any appearence of "<script>" from user inputs to be safe from XSS.

Comment: IE does not url-decode html, nor the whole http-response-content. i've just checked.

Comment: You’ll get `<script>…` when the server URL-decodes twice.

Comment: why would it be decoded twice? it's on the http response content, it shouldn't be decoded even once..

Comment: Where does it state it bypasses the htmlspecialchars filter? Looks more like a blacklist filter prevention.

Comment: @PeeHaa I edited my question, and explained everything.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways:

- Simple XSS filters/IDS etc. looking for tags can be fooled if they don't decode twice
- It happens from time to time, due to the complexity of software, that application servers decode values twice
- It also happens that developers misunderstand the framework and add additional url decoding even though it has already been done by the server

**Edit:**
Here is an OWASP page describing the attack. At the bottom there are two links to real vulnerabilities:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Double_Encoding

Comment: Even if a developer misunderstood the framework, he would decode as soon as possible. meaning, BEFORE the validation. the interesting thing you said is about app servers that decode twice. are you aware of any? IIS? Apache? is this considered a bug? a security vulnerability? is it a known issue? under what condition it might happen?

Comment: Well here is an example of a mistake within a framework itself: http://www.ntdsxtract.com/downloads/struts2.pdf

Comment: Oh, and IIS had a bug like this in 2001 and it was considered a vulnerability. There are probably more recent examples.